# How to link to another view (from same controller) in rails from html erb file?

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

So I have my main page, landingpage.html.erb, and I want to put a link on there that will lead to another simple page with a few more links to outside sources.

landingpage.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "press", '/press', :method => :get %>
```

press.html.erb

```
<h1>Test!</h1>
```

(I also made a partial, to test if that would get displayed.  Its the same is press.html.erb but _press.html.erb)

Controller

```
def press
  end
```

Error I keep getting:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/press"
```

Where am I going wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the route to your `config/routes.rb` too. It depends on how you defined your other routes but a basic definition look like this:

```
get '/press', to: 'controller_name#press'
```

Read more about [Routing in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).